# basic commands of w3m

Tags: text-processing, html, format-conversion

I download a HTML file using `wget` command. I convert it into a text file using `w3m`.

```
wget -q0- www.example.com
w3m -dump index.html
```

I want to use only basic commands like `wget`, `curl`, etc. without installing any additional packages like `w3m`, `lynx` and `html2text` to convert HTML to text. Can you suggest some commands to do the same?

Any other method to get text of a webpage using basic commands are also appreciated.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: @Cyrus Please make that an answer!

Comment: So you want to parse a complex HTML/CSS/JavaScript document without using complex parsers? Or put it another way, you want to convert html to text without using a tool such as `html2text`? Or lets put it another way again, you want to download and parse an HTML file to convert to text, but only using a download tool like `wget` and not using a parsing and conversion tool like `w3m`? And someone should also make you a shirt without any needlework?